# How do you assign a static data- attribute to an ember view?

Tags: ember.js, custom-data-attribute

I need to assign a static data- attribute to an Ember.View, how do I set that in the View object instead of in the `{{view }}` tag.

```
App.MessagesFormView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  classNames: ['modal', 'fade'],
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().modal('show')
  },
  willDestroyElement: function() {
    this.$().modal('hide')
  },
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to comment on Ola's answer, but I believe a slightly better way to do this is to not use a string (text in quotation marks) to denote the data attribute property name. Instead, write your property name in camelCase and Ember will automatically bind it to the hyphenated attributebinding. For example:

```
App.MessagesFormView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  attributeBindings: ['data-backdrop'], 
  dataBackdrop: 'static', // Binds to data-backdrop. Awesome!
});
```

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: For some reason, this didn't work for me. I agree that it seems like the Ember Way, but didn't do it (I am biding attributes within a Component, not a View, maybe that changes things?)

Comment: Maybe an update of Ember removed this functionality?

Comment: @DuncanWalker which version of ember are you using?

Comment: Now 1.9.1 but I'm not sure of the version I was using when the question was originally answered.

Answer (score 4):

This has to be done using both an `attributeBindings` and `data-backdrop` or `data-whatever` property of the Ember.View object.

```
App.MessagesFormView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  classNames: ['modal', 'fade'],
  // Set a data attribute, of a view, requires both an attribute binding and
  // an attribute assignment
  attributeBindings: ['data-backdrop'],
  'data-backdrop': 'static',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().modal('show')
  },
  willDestroyElement: function() {
    this.$().modal('hide')
  },
})
```

Comment: Your example does the trick but does more than add a simple *static* attribute to the element. It will bind the attribute to the property value and will subsequently propagate property changes to the attribute, which may be an overkill for some use cases (bootstrap `data-toggle` anyone?). I suspect the only way to add a true static attribute is via `this.$().attr('data-toggle', 'collapse')` in `didInsertElement`.